# Docker repository does not exist

Tags: docker

Docker reports repository does not exist, but it is not truth

```
C:\Users\g> docker run prakhar99/static-site
Unable to find image 'prakhar99/static-site:latest' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for prakhar99/static-site, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

Why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct name of your image? Where have you found it?

Comment: Show what `docker images` tells you.

Comment: and `docker info` as well

Comment: I agree with @BernardoDuarte, you likely don't have the correct name for the image. I get the same error on OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Docker run` needs the image to exist. It's telling you it doesn't. There are **three options** for it to exist:

1. To exist on [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/).

This would mean that `prakhar99/static-site` should be splitted like: `prakhar99`, the name of the Docker Hub user, and `static-site` as the name of the image itself.

Since it doesn't exist in DockerHub, this is not what you're looking for.

2. To exist in your PC, which means that you have executed `Docker build` with a dockerfile and named it appropriately. Check the [docs here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).
3. It would be a different repository instead of the official Docker Hub repo. For example, NVIDIA maintains their own special Docker Repository [here](https://ngc.nvidia.com/). In this case, you would need to add the domain as a prefix, for example:

`docker pull nvcr.io/nvidia-hpcvis/paraview-index:5.7.0-egl-pvw`

If `docker run` tells you it doesn't find the image, it is because no one of them finds the image available. Check:

- If the recipe that you're following doesn't include a `Docker build` previously to create the image.
- If you're missing a different repository at the beginning of your `run` command.
- For typos in the command.

Answer (score 2):

Checking on docker hub, this user does not exist so the error message you're getting is correct as the repository does not exist.